# Magento: Set paid an order before making the bill

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to understand if there's a way to set and order, that must be paid with bank transfer, paid when I check that money as arrived on my account, and then after that make the bill some day after.. Because I don't find where to change the status, whitout making the bill. My need is to set paid to create than an observer that send an email to my supplier to start to produce goods to sell. So the customer must also wait 15 days, so the shipment and the bill can be done in the next month. For this reason an need a medium point between order and bill. Thank you! Bye

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense to create the invoice and set it to paid if the money arrived on your account. Unless you don't explain more about your intended workflow (and why you don't want to create an invoice) it hard to come up with another solution.

You might think about adding and using some more Order statuses (`System > Manage Order Statuses`) and trigger your events depending on the order status.

Comment: My problem is that the shipping could be made also in the next month of the invoice. So I don't know if in italy is possible to make that.. Make the bill before the shipping document. I've thinked to insert another order status, but I don't find where to change it on a single order